# sensu mailer handler using mail gem ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, centos, smtp, sensu

i am facing some issue using sensu mailer handler, please help me out to solve this issue

i think i am facing port issue, does anyone have any idea.

> "output":["/opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/smtp.rb:542:in `initialize': execution expired (Net::OpenTimeout)\n\tfrom /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/smtp.rb:542:in`open'\n\tfrom /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/smtp.rb:542:in `tcp_socket'\n\tfrom /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/smtp.rb:552:in`block in do_start'\n\tfrom /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/timeout.rb:101:in `timeout'\n\tfrom /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/smtp.rb:551:in`do_start'\n\tfrom /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/smtp.rb:521:in `start'\n\tfrom /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mail-2.6.4/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:113:in`deliver!'\n\tfrom /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mail-2.6.4/lib/mail/message.rb:2149:in `do_delivery'\n\tfrom /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mail-2.6.4/lib/mail/message.rb:239:in`deliver'\n\tfrom /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mail-2.6.4/lib/mail/mail.rb:141:in `deliver'\n\tfrom /etc/sensu/handlers/handler-mailer.rb:233:in`rescue in handle'\n\tfrom /etc/sensu/handlers/handler-mailer.rb:218:in `handle'\n\tfrom /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sensu-plugin-1.3.0/lib/sensu-handler.rb:57:in`block in '\n"]

Comment: What have you tried? What is your configuration? You best find the error if you try to send emails without sensu. Just use ruby to directly without sensu and it will be much quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the issue, firewall is blocking port 587.